# AWS athena sql query to get distinct data

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Below is the data I have in excel sheet. This data is stored in S3 bucket. This data gets updated continuously with DynamoDB streams data using lambda function.

```
rollno | status    |  name | place
----------------------------------
   1   | pending   |   x   | london 
   1   | approved  |   x   | london
   1   | progress  |   x   | london
   1   | completed |   x   | london
   2   | pending   |   y   | delhi
   2   | approved  |   y   | delhi
   2   | progress  |   y   | delhi
   3   | pending   |   z   | newyork
   3   | approved  |   z   | newyork 
   4   | pending   |   a   | seattle
```

As you can see only status is changing from `pending -> approved -> progress -> completed` for `rollno` and all other values same.

Table is created in AWS Athena. My goal is to query Athena and to get result in below format (getting details with latest status).

```
rollno | status    |  name | place
----------------------------------
   1   | completed |   x   | london
   2   | progress  |   y   | delhi
   3   | approved  |   z   | newyork
   4   | pending   |   a   | seattle
```

I am new to SQL. Can I please get help on writing SQL query to get above desired result. 
I tried but couldn't figure out a way to do it in SQL.

Comment: If you have a updated_time column you can simply query that and get the results.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. Even if I query with updated_time I still get duplicate values

Answer (score 2):

If you have the update_time column you can group by and get latest record. Here I have considered rollno to group. if you want you can group using name and place also

```
     select rolno,status,name,place from table_T where rollno||updated_time
     in
     (
     select rollno||max(updated_time) from table_T group by rollno
     )
```